# Including directives with phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

I am using yeoman to generate an angular application and deploying it with phonegap to a mobile platform (ios) to be exact, however I am having issues with getting directives to work.

I have a directive called "header" that basically does what it says on the box and displays a header and looks like this.

I am using yeoman to generate an angular application and deploying it with phonegap to a mobile platform (ios) to be exact, however I am having issues with getting directives to work.

I have a directive called "header" that basically does what it says on the box and displays a header and looks like this.

```
angular.module('myappApp').directive('header', function(contentUpdater) {

    function link(scope) {
        scope.contentUpdater = contentUpdater;
        scope.headerTextThin = scope.contentUpdater.getHeaderTextThin();
        scope.headerTextBold = scope.contentUpdater.getHeaderTextBold();
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link,
        scope: {
        },
        templateUrl: 'header.html'
    };
});
```

Even though it shows on the browser, when i simulate with phonegap run ios it doesn't show up. I do have the header in under app/scripts/directives/header.html and the js file in app/scripts/directives/header.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember whether Phonegap minifies code by default, but perhaps it is uglifying the Javascript before deploying it on the iOS?

In that case, this should fix the problem:

```
angular.module('myappApp').directive('header', 
['contentUpdater', function(contentUpdater) {
    // ...
}]);
```

Comment: @adanalig Could minification be messing up some other injection?